# Ajax Jquery : Ajax function onclick wont complete or post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I'm about to lose my mind, I have gone over the documentation twice and can't understand whats up with it, im not even able to recieve an alert in the event of an error: or success:

please tell me someone has some ideas...

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <li><a href="#" id="restuatant"><span class="t">restaurant</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" value="active"> <span class="t">hair salon</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" value="bars"> <span class="t">bars</span></a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" value="other"> <span class="t">other</span></a></li></form>src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {
                       'categories': $(this).find("span.t").text(),
                         }
                   url: {% url 'search' %},
                   success: function(data){
                        alert('data submited')
                                       }
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('error');
                                    }
            });
            </script>
```

Where {% url 'search' %} is:

```
 url(r"^loc_search/$", 'project_name.views.json_search', name="search"),
```

All i want to do is pass what ever option is selected into my function in my views.py file :(

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you aren't separating each property in the ajax call with a comma (missing it after data, after success). Any errors coming in the console? Does the request appear in the network tab of the console? How does the served JavaScript look (after server processing, as in, the source code once your page loads)?

Comment: idk what this garbage does `{% url 'search' %}`. What does the outputted javascript look like? Probably it's supposed to be a string but it's not wrapped in quotes. Check your js errors

Comment: Do you have a copy-paste error? You're missing the `</ul>` to end the list, and you have `</script>src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">` -- the `<script` is missing.

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar That's from a template framework.

Comment: it doesn't output anything, but when i pull it with using ajax it just outputs a string